# Why can't I connect to a SQL database from Node.js application on Mac?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I guess my initial question is, is it possible to connect to a sql database using the npm mssql module from a node application on a mac? I figured the mssql module was just an alternative to tedious.js - am I wrong? Is it just for windows use?

```
var db = require("mssql");

var config = {
  server: server,
  user: user,
  password: password,
  database: database
};

var connection = new db.Connection(config);

connection.connect(config, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
  }

  console.log("Success.");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I missed the [docs](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) recommendation to add `encrypt: true` to the config options if using Windows Azure.  Added that and it worked fine. It wasn't giving me any error messages beforehand, so it took a while to figure out XD

```
var config = {
  server: server,
  user: user,
  password: password,
  database: database,
  options: {
    encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
  }
};
```